# How to display two different legends in hconcat chart using altair

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, altair

I need to display two separate charts side by side including their legends in Jupyterlab and the only way I managed to do that was using hconcat.
I've gotten this far:

[image]

However even with  `.resolve_legend(color='independent')` I get the entries from both charts displayed in both legends at the top - which is mighty confusing.

The result should look like this:

[image]

How can I remove the unwanted legend entries?
Or if anyone knows a good alternative how to have to charts side-by-side in a single jupyterlab cell I would be happy to take a different route.

My code looks like this:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from altair.expr import datum
df_test=pd.read_csv("test_df.csv")

chart_m1=alt.Chart(df_test).mark_bar().encode(
            x=alt.X('counts:Q', stack="normalize",axis=None),
            y=alt.Y('category:N',sort=['A','B','C'],title=None),
            color=alt.Color('grade:N',
                sort = alt.EncodingSortField( 'sort:Q', order = 'ascending' ),
                scale = alt.Scale(domain=['good <10', 'average 10-20', 'bad >20'], range=['#0cce6b', '#ffa400', '#ff4e42']),
                legend = alt.Legend(title="Metric1",orient='top')),
            order='sort:Q',
            tooltip=['category:N','grade:N','counts:Q']
            ).transform_filter(datum.metric=='metric1'
            ).properties(height=50,width=150)

chart_m2=alt.Chart(df_test).mark_bar().encode(
            x=alt.X('counts:Q', stack="normalize",axis=None),
            y=alt.Y('category:N',sort=['A','B','C'],title=None),
            color=alt.Color('grade:N',
                sort = alt.EncodingSortField( 'sort:Q', order = 'ascending' ),
                scale = alt.Scale(domain=['good <100', 'average 100-350', 'bad >350'], range=['#0cce6b', '#ffa400', '#ff4e42']),
                legend = alt.Legend(title="Metric2",orient='top')),
            order='sort:Q',
            tooltip=['category:N','grade:N','counts:Q']
            ).transform_filter(datum.metric=='metric2'
            ).properties(height=50,width=150)

alt.hconcat(chart_m1,chart_m2).resolve_legend(color='independent').configure_view(stroke=None)
```

The `test_df.csv` I used is this:

```
category,metric,sort,grade,counts
A,metric1,1,good <10,345
B,metric1,1,good <10,123
C,metric1,1,good <10,567
A,metric1,2,average 10-20,567
B,metric1,2,average 10-20,678
C,metric1,2,average 10-20,789
A,metric1,3,bad >20,900
B,metric1,3,bad >20,1011
C,metric1,3,bad >20,1122
A,metric2,1,good <100,1122
B,metric2,1,good <100,1011
C,metric2,1,good <100,900
A,metric2,2,average 100-350,789
B,metric2,2,average 100-350,678
C,metric2,2,average 100-350,567
A,metric2,3,bad >350,567
B,metric2,3,bad >350,345
C,metric2,3,bad >350,123
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `resolve_scale(color='independent')`

```
alt.hconcat(
    chart_m1, chart_m2
).resolve_scale(
    color='independent'
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

[image]

More information at https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html

Comment: Ha - perfect, exactly what I need. Thanks